# Prevent web site reload after take picture using HTML5 Camera API

Tags: javascript, html

I need take a photo in a web application and I use `HTML5 Camera API` This is the simple code:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload"  accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

The problem is in android, when take a picture the site is reload. How can I prevent the site from being reload after taking the photo?

Comment: you need to use javascript to prevent its default. Read more about here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/API/Camera_API/Introduction

Comment: The example on the mozilla developer site dont prevent the reload after select the image

Comment: After reload the android phone, the problem is solve.... So, Its a android problem...